# remove all of the vowels from string and print new string with no vowels

Tags: python

the goal is to write a code that removes all of the vowels in a user inputted string;  my code wont print a final new_inp string with no vowels. It seems that the line    new_inp=inp.replace(ch,"")    does not do anything. Anyone? Thank you.

```
inp="je m'en fou!"
vocals=['a','e','i','o','u']
for ch in inp.lower():
    if ch in vocals:
        new_inp=inp.replace(ch,"")
        print (new_inp)
```

Comment: Vous n'êtes pas fou

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
inp="je m'en fou!"
vocals=['a','e','i','o','u']
for ch in inp.lower():
    if ch in vocals:
        inp=inp.replace(ch,"")
        print (inp)
```

You were overwriting the string each iteration of the loop with the original string instead of accumulating changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to accumulate all the updates in one string. Your current approach only replaces from the initial string and discards the previous updates in next iterations:

```
new_inp = inp
for ch in inp.lower():
    if ch in vocals:
        new_inp = new_inp.replace(ch,"")
        print(new_inp)
```

You can achieve the same using the following generator expression that filters out non vowel items:

```
new_inp = ''.join(x for x in inp if x not in vocals)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `re` module.

```
import re
inp="je m'en fou!"
re.sub('[aeiou]', '', inp)
```

Output:

```
"j m'n f!"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to do just that:

```
inp="je m'en fou!"
vocals='aeiou'

new_inp = ''.join(letter for letter in inp if letter not in vocals)
print(new_inp)  # j m'n f!
```

the problem with your approach is that you start with the original string in every iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the inp variable.

```
inp="je m'en fou!"
vocals=['a','e','i','o','u']
for ch in inp.lower():
    if ch in vocals:
        inp=inp.replace(ch,'')
        print (inp)
```